# adb shell communication by python

Tags: python, android, adb

I would like to write a python script which allows communication by adb shell.

python script should be able to open adb shell, change directories and start the apps.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p=Popen('adb shell',shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

and the I would like to read and write by

```
p.stdout.read()

p.stdin.write("ls -l")
p.stdin.flush()
```

but it doesn't work.

Only if I change shell=True. The cmd window open and after I close manually the window I can read one time the response.

Does anybody have an idea, what I can do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When writing `ls -l` you need to add new line otherwise the command is never executed...

Comment: Thanks,
I have to use p.stdin.write("ls -l\n")

But I am also not able to read. The process is running in endless loop

Comment: You have to read from stdout line by line not everything at once (or at least with a time-out).

Comment: yes, it's clear.
If I send the command "adb connect" , I am able to read "connected to ..."
but if I send command "adb shell" , I am not able to read.  The process is hanging. Only if I kill "adb.exe" in task manager, I get "'root@localhost:~# '"